# Trouble getting a union query to work across different models in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I'm using Wagtail, and I have two models that have some fields in common. I would like to get a query of the union of those common fields. Here are the models:

```
class VideoPage(Page):

  image = models.ForeignKey("wagtailimages.Image", blank=False, null=True, related_name="+", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  vimeo_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  publish_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, default=datetime.date.today)
  category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True, default="Videos")
  pdf = models.ForeignKey('wagtaildocs.Document', null=True, blank=False, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+')

class CustomerHubFile(models.Model):

  CASESTUDY = 'Case Study'
  DATASHEET = 'Data Sheet'
  SOLUTIONBRIEF = 'Solution Brief'
  CATEGORY = [
    (CASESTUDY, _('Case Study')),
    (DATASHEET, _('Data Sheet')),
    (SOLUTIONBRIEF, _('Solution Brief')),
  ]

  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  pdf = models.ForeignKey('wagtaildocs.Document', null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  related_name='+')
  image = models.ForeignKey("wagtailimages.Image", blank=False, null=True, related_name="+", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  help_text="The image for the PDF")
  publish_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
  category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True, choices=CATEGORY, default=CASESTUDY, verbose_name="Category")
```

Then I'm trying to add a query that joins both of these models together and return it in the context. I can't use values() or value_list() because I need access to the models in the template in order to use the images. I'd think I should be able to do it using only() like this:

```
pdfs = CustomerHubFile.objects.all().only('title', 'image', 'publish_date', 'category_name')
videos = VideoPage.objects.all().only('title', 'image', 'publish_date', 'category_name')
records = pdfs.union(videos).order_by('-publish_date')
context["records"] = records
return context
```

Unfortunately, only() also gets the id, but it doesn't get them in the same order for both models, which messes up the JOIN, resulting in an error that says "UNION types integer and character varying cannot be matched". Here is the generated SQL:

```
(
        SELECT "customer_hub_customerhubfile"."id",
               "customer_hub_customerhubfile"."title",
               "customer_hub_customerhubfile"."image_id",
               "customer_hub_customerhubfile"."publish_date",
               "customer_hub_customerhubfile"."category_name"
          FROM "customer_hub_customerhubfile"
         ORDER BY "customer_hub_customerhubfile"."publish_date" DESC
       )
 UNION (
        SELECT "wagtailcore_page"."title",
               "customer_hub_videopage"."page_ptr_id",
               "customer_hub_videopage"."image_id",
               "customer_hub_videopage"."publish_date",
               "customer_hub_videopage"."category_name"
          FROM "customer_hub_videopage"
         INNER JOIN "wagtailcore_page"
            ON ("customer_hub_videopage"."page_ptr_id" = "wagtailcore_page"."id")
         ORDER BY "wagtailcore_page"."path" ASC
       )
```

I tried specifying the id fields in the only() but it still doesn't get them in specified order. Is there any way to get the ids to return as the first column for both queries, or is there another way I can get this union to work?

Comment: You might try using Python's 'itertools.chain()' instead.

Comment: That will allow me to combine the queries, but I can't order by publish_date across all queries. Instead, it will iterate through everything in the first query and then move on to the second.